# Prove or disprove: if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=3$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(\frac {1}{n})$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Just learned about series recently and been trying to solve this question and I got stuck, the derivative that is taking me to taylor's polynomial, but I have no idea how to link between it and my series. 
 Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try $f(x)=3x{}$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $f(0)$ isn't defined there :)

Comment: @boink it was a typo -- now fixed! :D

Comment: Taylor tells you that $f(h) = f(0) + f'(0)h + \mathcal{O}(h^2) = 3h +  \mathcal{O}(h^2)$ for small $h$ so a comparison test with the series $a_n = \frac{3}{n}$ is a natural thing to try (if you want to prove that it diverges for all $f$ satisfying the conditions - but as written a single counter example would do).

Comment: @Winther Scratch my last comment -- The great thing about your argument is that, except continuous differentiability at $0$, nothing is assumed about $f$ ! (I think actually to not use any assumptions, $\mathcal O(h^2)$ would have to be replaced by $\mathcal o(h)$, but otherwise it works.)

Comment: @Winther Thanks for the help, I'm really still new and struggling to understand the use of $h$, is it usually used like this to link between taylor's polynomial and series? or is it a smart trick you used specificly for this question? (sorry just never saw it like that before).

Comment: You are given some information about how $f$ behaves at $x=0$ and Taylor series is the key formula that approximates $f$ in the neighborhood from that kind of information. The general term in your series is $f$ at a point, $x=1/n$, that for large $n$ is very close to $x=0$. Thus this approach comes out quite natural from thinking about this (but of course its easier to see with time when you have more experience). That said the approach in the answer below is probably easier to understand at this stage.

Comment: @Winther Appreciate the explanation, I get the idea now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One counterexample suffices, the obvious one being $f(x)=3x$, but the general result that **all** $f$ satisfying the given conditions result in a divergent series can be obtained directly from the definition of the derivative. Since $f(0)=0$, you know that

$$3=f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}h\,,$$

so there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $2<\frac{f(h)}h<4$ whenever $|h|<\epsilon$. Thus, for $n>\frac1\epsilon$ we must have

$$2<\frac{f\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1n}<4$$

and hence

$$\frac2n<f\left(\frac1n\right)<\frac4n\,.$$

But then $\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}f\left(\frac1n\right)$ diverges by comparison with $\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac2n$.

Comment: I was gonna say that